# SQL Server procedure does not allow insert equal value if already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, overlapping

I have this procedure in which I try to add a minute to the parameter `@HORA_I` or allow to insert the same start time to the existing end time

- start_time = @HORA_I
- end_time = @HORA_F

I need to insert a `start_time` but if an `end_time` with the same value of `start_time`  already exists, then allow to insert the same value that already exist not more no less just the same or add 1 minute to the `start_time` (`@HORA_I`)

For example:

I have a existing `end_time` with the value of 13:00 and I want to insert a new event with the `start_time` (`@HORA_I`) 13:00 and this must be inserted.

```
    @DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(500),
    @ID_SALA INT,
    @ID_TIPO_SOLICITANTE INT,
    @FECHA SMALLDATETIME,
    @HORA_I NVARCHAR(5),
    @HORA_F NVARCHAR(5),
    @ID_PRESTATARIO INT,
    @ID_USUARIO INT,
    @SOLICITANTE NVARCHAR(150),
    @AUTORIZACION INT
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PRESTAMO_SALA
               WHERE ID_SALA = @ID_SALA
                 AND [FECHA_PRESTAMO] = @FECHA --LA FECHA
                 AND ((@HORA_I BETWEEN HORA_INICIO AND HORA_FIN)
                      OR (@HORA_F BETWEEN HORA_INICIO AND HORA_FIN)
                      OR(@HORA_I >= HORA_FIN AND @HORA_F >= HORA_INICIO)
                     )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Ya existe un evento en esa fecha, sala y horario, porfavor ingrese otra hora de inicio y hora fin.',18,1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON

       DECLARE @hora_inicio NVARCHAR(5) = @HORA_I

       SELECT CAST(CAST(DATEADD(minute, 1, CAST(@hora_inicio AS DATETIME)) AS TIME) AS nvarchar(5))

       DECLARE @ID_PERIODO INT

       SELECT @ID_PERIODO = ID_PERIODO FROM CAT_PERIODOS WHERE ACTIVO = 1

       INSERT INTO PRESTAMO_SALA (DESCRIPCION, ID_SALA, ID_TIPO_SOLICITANTE, 
                                  FECHA_PRESTAMO, HORA_INICIO, HORA_FIN, 
                                  ID_PRESTATARIO,  ID_USUARIO, ID_PERIODO, 
                                  FECHA_REG, SOLICITANTE, ID_AUTORIZACION)
       VALUES(@DESCRIPCION, @ID_SALA, @ID_TIPO_SOLICITANTE, 
              @FECHA, @hora_inicio, @HORA_F, 
              @ID_PRESTATARIO, @ID_USUARIO, @ID_PERIODO, 
              GETDATE(), @SOLICITANTE, @AUTORIZACION)

       SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID_PRESTAMO_SALA
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should server your purpose

```
DECLARE @HORA_I VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @HORA_F VARCHAR(5)

SET @HORA_I = '13:59'
SET @HORA_F = '13:59'

IF @HORA_F = @HORA_I OR @HORA_F IS NULL
SET @HORA_F = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEADD(MINUTE,1,CAST('2000-01-01 '+@HORA_I AS DATETIME)),108)
-- Add 1 minute to time

PRINT @HORA_I
PRINT @HORA_F
```